# Plugin for outlook mobile installed in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, outlook

I followed outlook model till POOM present in windows mobile 6.5, I have no clue if we can develop an addin for outlook installed with windows phone 7, if yes where can I find sdk related to it or any code samples.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 doesn't allow full access to Outlook data as WM6.5 did. The closest you're going to get is to write an app for WP7.5 (Mango) that uses the Contacts and Calendar integration feature. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202972(v=vs.92).aspx.

You can also call out to make limited modifications using "choosers" - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769543(v=VS.92).aspx